# Capture raw internet traffic

Tags: wireshark, portable, network-monitoring

I am sure that this has been asked before, but I can't find exactly what I am looking for.

I am looking for a *free* *standalone* program that allows one to record all traffic between a computer (my computer) and the router. I would like to be able to see the *raw data* that is being sent back and forth. And if possible I would like to be able to record the data and save it.

I tried using Wireshark, but it required installing winpcap.

I am on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Comment: You could use virtualbox to create a linux VM, and then run a tcp dump on the network.

Comment: What is wrong with winpcap?  It's just installing a driver used to capture the raw packets and a library to access the data captured by that driver.  Without that driver you can't capture raw packets on Windows.

Comment: @spuder: Is this the virtualbox you are talking about: https://www.virtualbox.org/ ? Does this require installation?

Comment: @heavyd: Ok, I didn't know that. If you add that as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: @Thomas, yes that is the virtual box, it is a virtualization technology that allows you to create virtual operating systems on your own computer. If you are going for simplicity, winpcap and wireshark still may be your best option.

Comment: @spuder: Where can one find a standalone version?

Comment: @Thomas There isn't a stand alone version, you would need to combine them yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the tool most commonly used to capture raw network packets.

On Windows, Wireshark depends on the [Winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library to do the capture.  Winpcap installs a driver which captures the network traffic and a library which is used to access the captured data.  Without the driver, it is not possible to capture raw packets on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) claims to be able to do captures without installing any driver/library, with certain limitations.

From the information on their website, it sounds like under Windows 7 you'll be able to see the raw IP-and-above data this way, but not the Ethernet headers.

If you want to see the Ethernet headers under Windows, you're going to have to install something into your system that will allow the Windows network stack to provide that information to your app. No "standalone" app will be able to do it.